# Cypress IO- Writing a For Loop

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have 15 buttons on a page. I need to test each button.

I tried a simple for loop, like

```
for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) {

   cy.get("[=buttonid=" + i + "]").click()
}
```

But Cypress didn't like this. How would I write for loops in Cypress?

Comment: What is Int? You can only declare variables with `var`, `let` and `const` in JS, right?

Comment: Oops my bad. I rewrote this, and I put int instead of var @konekoya

Comment: What do you mean Cypress "didn't like it"? Was an error thrown? Did you mean to prefix `buttonid` with an equals sign? Does `cy.get` return anything?

Comment: The for loop is not what is broken here - I think your selector is incorrect (should likely be `buttonid=`, not `=buttonid=`). Please include the error message given by cypress, as well as enough HTML to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 48):

To force an arbitrary loop, I create an array with the indices I want, and then call `cy.wrap`

```
var genArr = Array.from({length:15},(v,k)=>k+1)
cy.wrap(genArr).each((index) => {
    cy.get("#button-" + index).click()
})
```

Comment: This is the only reliable way, at least if the order of code execution is important. It's worth noting that - due to the asynchronous nature of cypress - a classical for loop will likely result in a non-deterministic execution order of the cy.* calls inside the loop.

Comment: Why do you do length:250? Shouldn't it be 15 iterations per the OP's question?

Answer (score 4):

[Lodash](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/_) is bundled with Cypress and methods are used with `Cypress._` prefix.

For this instance, you'll be using the [`_.times`](https://docs-lodash.com/v4/times/). So your code will look something like this:

```
Cypress._.times(15, (k) => {
   cy.get("[=buttonid=" + k + "]").click()
})
```

Comment: Does the behavior work like for(...) when using Cypress._.time? If so, I think you didn't fix the issue because the for(...) isn't synchronous. You have to use `cy.wrap().each()`.

Comment: I believe as it is called via Cypress API, it should be synchronous flow. I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something similar to a "for loop" by using recursion.

I just posted a solution here: [How to use a while loop in cypress? The control of is NOT entering the loop when running this spec file? The way I am polling the task is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591716/how-to-use-a-while-loop-in-cypress-the-control-of-is-not-entering-the-loop-when/72512125#72512125)

Add this to your custom commands:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('recursionLoop', {times: 'optional'}, function (fn, times) {
  if (typeof times === 'undefined') {
    times = 0;
  }

  cy.then(() => {
    const result = fn(++times);
    if (result !== false) {
      cy.recursionLoop(fn, times);
    }
  });
});
```

Then you can use it by creating a function that returns `false` when you want to stop iterating.

```
cy.recursionLoop(times => {
  cy.wait(1000);
  console.log(`Iteration: ${times}`);
  console.log('Here goes your code.');
  return times < 5;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

While `cy.wrap().each()` will work (one of the answers given for this question), I wanted to give an alternate way that worked for me. `cy.wrap().each()` will work, but regular while/for loops will not work with cypress because of the async nature of cypress. Cypress doesn't wait for everything to complete in the loop before starting the loop again. You can however do recursive functions instead and that waits for everything to complete before it hits the method/function again.

Here is a simple example to explain this. You could check to see if a button is visible, if it is visible you click it, then check again to see if it is still visible, and if it is visible you click it again, but if it isn't visible it won't click it. This will repeat, the button will continue to be clicked until the button is no longer visible. Basically the method/function is called over and over until the conditional is no longer met, which accomplishes the same thing as a for/while loop, but actually works with cypress.

```
clickVisibleButton = () => {
        cy.get( 'body' ).then( $mainContainer => {
            const isVisible = $mainContainer.find( '#idOfElement' ).is( ':visible' );
            if ( isVisible ) {
                cy.get( '#idOfElement' ).click();
                this.clickVisibleButton();
            }
        } );
    }
```

Then obviously call the `this.clickVisibleButton()` in your test. I'm using typescript and this method is setup in a class, but you could do this as a regular function as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the test case requires checking within HTML elements in a recursive manner, then Cypress `alias` can be used. Additionally, the method can be called recursively inside the `cy. ... .then()`

Example -

For my use case, I wanted to test the UI by looping through multiple pages of a table. The pagination element was aliased and based on whether a particular text is found or not, the method is called repeatedly.

The UI had a pagnation element that is numbered as 1,2 .... By default page 1 is selected.

Adding a screenshot for reference.
[image]

*Code Snippet*

```
let index = 2; //start navigating from the second page

cy.get('#table').as('Table');

const goToNextPage = () => {
  cy.get('@Table').then(($odt) => {
    if ($odt.html().includes(oCode)) {
      cy.get('.order-history-code a').should('contain', oCode);
    } else { 
      //element not found, keep searching in the next page
      cy.get('pagination').findByText(index).first().click();
      index++;
      cy.wait('@API').then(goToNextPage);
    }
  });
};

goToNextPage();
```

This snippet was inspired from [this medium](https://medium.com/@rojek.mac/testing-pagination-with-cypress-io-c4376395417f) post

Answer (score -3):

// waits 2 seconds for each attempt

```
refreshQuote(attempts) {
    let arry = []
    for (let i = 0; i < attempts; i++) { arry.push(i) }
    cy.wrap(arry).each(() => {
        cy.get('.quote-wrapper').then(function($quoteBlock) {
            if($quoteBlock.text().includes('Here is your quote')) {
            }
            else {
                cy.get('#refreshQuoteButton').click()
                cy.wait(2000)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Try template literals using backticks:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    cy.get(`ul li:nth-child(`${i}`)).click();
}
```

Comment: this will have no effect - see the other answers above.