# Cypress wait for an element to be loaded inside a foor loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, cypress, browser-automation, ui-testing

I have an array, which items are a bunch of button elements. I want to call a button then wait for an element(which is in the dom) to be loaded.

after that element loaded, then only I want to go to the next iteration (click on the next button/element)

In my current implementation, all buttons are clicked at a time. but I want one button should be clicked at a time.

```
  cy.document().then(document => {
      const arra = [...document.querySelectorAll('.instances__action')];

      for (let i = 1; i <= arra.length; i++) {
        let state = document.querySelector(
          `#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(3) > span`
        ).innerText;

        document
          .querySelector(
            `#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i}) > td:nth-child(7) > div > button.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary.ant-btn-sm`
          )
          .click();
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.waitUntil(() => {
          cy.get(
            `#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(${i +
              1}) > td:nth-child(3) > span`
          ).contains('Finished');
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress IO- Writing a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52212868/cypress-io-writing-a-for-loop)

Comment: well, It will not ensure that the second button is called after the first button. as it is async in nature

Comment: In general, I think you'll have more success if you use the constructs Cypress gives you rather than plain javascript.

Answer (score 2):

@jmargolisvt is correct, if you change the `.click()` operation to a Cypress command, you should get the correct sequence of actions.

**Command execution sequence and test loops**

Think of it like this - the test code above runs as normal javascript, and each `cy.X()` command puts a command into the queue. Commands are guaranteed to run sequentially in the queue order, but not synchronously with the test code.

So, the the `cy.wait(2000)` is not slowing down the for-loop, it's pausing the queue execution.

**Waiting for assertions**

Note also that commands have built-in waits for their assertions, so you probably don't need either the `cy.wait()` or the `cy.waitUntil()` in this scenario. You can control the ***maximum*** time for waiting with a `timeout` option.

**Looping**

The for loop will work ok if you convert the inner parts to commands, but you can also convert the loop itself to a [cy.get().each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html#Examples) command which IMO is much neater.

**Testing async content**

Lastly, prefer `cy.contains('mySelector', 'myContent')` command to  `cy.get('mySelector').contains('myContent')` command when waiting for async content.

The reason is `cy.get('mySelector').contains('myContent')` only waits on the element `mySelector`, but it's already in the DOM. If the content is asynchronously changing, this command will test the old content (presume empty) immediately and fail the test.

```js
const tbodySelector = '#root > section > section > main > div > div > section.instances > div > div > div > div > div > div > table > tbody';
const buttonSelector = 'td:nth-child(7) > div > button.ant-btn.ant-btn-primary.ant-btn-sm';
const spanSelector = 'td:nth-child(3) > span'

cy.get('.instances__action').each(($el, i) => {

    cy.get(`${tbodySelector} > tr:nth-child(${i+1}) > ${buttonSelector}`)
      .click();

    cy.contains(
      `${tbodySelector} > tr:nth-child(${i+1}) > ${spanSelector}`, 
      'Finished', 
      { timeout: 2000 }  // increase timeout if a longer wait is required
    );  

});
```

---

**NOTE** jQuery's `:nth-child(index)` selector starts at index 1, but `.each(($el, i) =>` has zero-based indexes, so must use `i+1` within these selectors.

---

This is the mock DOM I used to test with. In a clean Cypress project, put it in folder `<project root>/app`.

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="instances__action">
      <td>
        <button id="myBtn1"></button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="mySpan1"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="instances__action">
      <td>
        <button id="myBtn2"></button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span id="mySpan2"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myBtn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("mySpan1").innerHTML = "Finished";
    }, 1000)
  });
  document.getElementById("myBtn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.getElementById("mySpan2").innerHTML = "Finished";
    }, 500)
  });
</script>
```

Note the nesting above is simplified, so I changed the selector contants appropriately.

**Testing the above HTML fragment**

```
it('clicks buttons and waits for finished flag', () => {

  cy.visit('app/iterate-table-buttons.html')

  const tbodySelector = 'tbody';
  const buttonSelector = 'td:nth-child(1) > button';
  const spanSelector = 'td:nth-child(2) > span'

  cy.get('.instances__action').each(($el, i) => {

      console.log(`starting #${i}`)

      cy.get(`${tbodySelector} > tr:nth-child(${i+1}) > ${buttonSelector}`)
        .then(() => console.log(`clicking #${i}`))
        .click();

      cy.contains(
        `${tbodySelector} > tr:nth-child(${i+1}) > ${spanSelector}`, 
        'Finished',
        { timeout: 2000 }  // increase timeout if a longer wait is required
      )
      .then(() => console.log(`asserting #${i}`))

  });
})
```

**Cypress log**

This is what the Cypress log looks like.
All green, and can see the clicks only happen after the Finished text appears.

1. VISIT      app/iterate-table-buttons.html
2. GET        .instances__action
3. GET        tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > button
4. CLICK
5. CONTAINS  tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > span, Finished
6. GET       tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > button
7. CLICK
8. CONTAINS  tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2) > span, Finished

**Console log**

This is what the console logs look like.

The loop executes to completion before the command queue even begins, but that's ok because the commands are still executing in correct order.

starting #0
starting #1
clicking #0
asserting #0
clicking #1
asserting #1

Comment: I tried this, but the same problem remains.
It clicks on the start button but then, before completing the action, it clicks the next start button.

I mean the selector not contains `finished` but still it goes to the next start button  and clicks it!

Comment: what is more strange is that if I give a wrong text in contains, for exaple I give `Finishes` in place of `finished`, It clicks on the first button, then looking for that `Finishes`
it didn't find that and test crashes.

but when I use correct text, It didn't wait until `finished` is loaded into the dom! 
instead it go to the next iteration of the loop

Comment: It worked for me in a mock-up of the DOM I think you have. I'll post it below the answer and you can compare it to the live scenario you have.