# Cypress: Async function using for loop giving same results

Tags: cypress

I'm new to cypress framework and trying to achieve the below functionality using cypress.

I have a page with table rows and a dropdown menu on page header. On selecting the option, the dropdown menu gets closed and the body content gets changed/loaded up according to the selected menu options.

Problem: Getting the same length for the table rows for all the menu options selected sequentially, although the table rows count is different for the options.

Here is my code:

```js
it.only('Validate table Row changed length on menu option selection', {defaultCommandTimeout: 10000}, () => {
  // opening the dropdown menu
  page.openDropdownMenu();
  // getting the dropdown options and calculating the length
  cy.get('dropdownOptions').then($options => {
    // calculating the length
    const menuOptionCount = $options.length;
    // closing the dropdown menu
    page.closeDropdownMenu();
    for (let i = 0; i < menuOptionCount; i++) {
      // opening the dropdown menu
      page.openDropdownMenu();
      // clicking the menu option
      $options[i].click();
      // closing the dropdown menu
      page.closeDropdownMenu();
      cy.get("body").then($body => {
        // always getting the same length for the table rows for all selected options
        const rowsLength = $body.find('.table.rows').length;
        cy.log('****************Rows length************', rowsLength);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any way to write the asynchronous statement to synchronous like (await async in promises) without using any external utility in cypress. As in my previous assignment using [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/) the same thing could be handled using async await as below.

```js
const elementCount = await element(
  by.css('[title="Locked By"] .med-filter-header-button div')
).count();
```

Comment: [`.each`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each) is what you want to use. You can loop over an arbitrary number by using the [`.wrap`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap) method as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53487016/864233 for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `click()` the app rewrites the table, but Cypress does not know that happens and gets the row count before the change occurs.

**TLDR** - You need to give Cypress more information test correctly. Generally, your test data should be known (not "discovered" by the test code).

---

**Problem #1**

You need some way to wait for the row change to finish. Either some text element changes (maybe the first row text), or by adding a `.should()` on the actual row count.

Something like

```js
const expectedRowCount = [5, 4, 3, 2]

cy.get('dropdownOptions').each(($option, index) => {

  page.openDropdownMenu()
  $option.click()
  page.closeDropdownMenu()

  cy.get('.table.rows')
    .should('have.length', expectedRowCount[index])  // this will retry until rowsLength changes
    .then(rowsLength => {
      cy.log('****************Rows length************', rowsLength)
    })
})
```

**Problem #2**

If **"the body content gets changed/loaded"** means that the dropdown ***also*** gets rewritten with every click, then the loop will fail because `$options` gets refreshed each time.

You might use the `expectedRowCount` to loop instead

```js
const expectedRowCount = [5, 4, 3, 2]

expectedRowCount.forEach((expectedCount, index) => {

  page.openDropdownMenu()
  cy.get('dropdownOptions').eq(index).click()
  page.closeDropdownMenu()

  cy.get('.table.rows')
    .should('have.length', expectedCount)  // retries until rowsLength changes
    .then(rowsLength => {
      cy.log('****************Rows length************', rowsLength)
    })
})
```

The above strategies do not really give you the most solid test.

If you can, check some text that changes upon each iteration,

```js
page.openDropdownMenu()
cy.get('dropdownOptions').then($options => {

  let firstRowText = '';   // to control the loop, waiting for this to change

  const menuOptionCount = $options.length;
  page.closeDropdownMenu();
  for (let i = 0; i < menuOptionCount; i++) {
  
    page.openDropdownMenu();
    cy.get('dropdownOptions').eq(i).click();  // fresh query each time through the loop

    page.closeDropdownMenu();

    cy.get('.table.rows').first().invoke('text')
      .should('not.eq', firstRowText);            // retry until text has changed
      .then(newText => firstRowText = newText);   // save for next loop

    cy.get('.table.rows').then($rows => {
      const rowsLength = $rows.length;
      cy.log('****************Rows length************', rowsLength);
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can condense your code to something like this. Instead of using a for loop, use `each` which is a cypress inbuilt method for looping.

```js
it.only(
  'Validate table Row changed length on menu option selection',
  {defaultCommandTimeout: 10000},
  () => {
    page.openDropdownMenu()
    cy.get('dropdownOptions').each(($options, index) => {
      cy.wrap($options).eq(index).click()
      page.closeDropdownMenu()
      cy.get('.table.rows')
        .its('length')
        .then((rowsLength) => {
          cy.log('****************Rows length************', rowsLength)
        })
      page.openDropdownMenu()
    })
    page.closeDropdownMenu()
  }
)
```