# Cypress automation not reacting on time with code

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I'm creating a Google flights automation with Cypress which is not working the way it should.
Basically, I enter to a bar graph that represents each day flight prices. The automation is supposed to loop through it one by one, bu clicking each element.
The problem is that, while looping through the graph with a for loop, it only clicks half of the times. After it begins looping, the automation only clicks the bars half of the times, which causes the automation to stop at the half because it works with indexes.

[image]

Here for instance, we can see the automation clicking the eighth bar after looping 14 times, 15 won't click, 16 will, 17 won't and like that.
It's more or less: 1 yes, 2 yes, 3 no, 4 yes, 5 no, 6 yes, 7 no, etc...

This is the code right now:

```
for(let i = indice; i<61; i++){

        let fechaSinProcesar = '';
        let precio = '';

        await lista.locator(graficoDePreciosPage.barraPrecioDiario + '[' + i + ']').click({force : true});
        if(await page.locator(graficoDePreciosPage.precioDeVuelo).isVisible()){           
            precio = await page.locator(graficoDePreciosPage.precioDeVuelo).textContent();
            fechaSinProcesar = await page.locator(graficoDePreciosPage.fechaDeVuelo).textContent();
        }

        let fecha = fechaSinProcesar.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
        jsonVuelos[fecha] = precio;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the Cypress code you're using instead of abstractions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress has a `.each()` command to use instead of the for-loop.

```js
cy.get('bar-graph-locator').each(($el,i) => {

  // test each bar here

})
```

The for-loop is no good, because you want each iteration of the test to wait for the previous one to finish before moving on to the next one.

Instead, it loops faster than the page can be tested, and you get the problem you have observed.

There is another answer to this problem here [Cypress IO- Writing a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53487016/16997707)

Also, instead of `if (...visible)` you should add the `:visible` selector to the element selector, something like

```js
cy.get('bar-graph-locator:visible').each(($el,i) => {

  // test each visible bar here

})
```